# nethack with big tiles

Tags: games

I am trying to play nethack on Ubuntu.

I really  want a graphical representation of the game (rather than text), and would prefer to command via the keyboard (rather than mouse).

My problem with xnethack is that the assets look to small and I strain to play the game. I have found glhack, but it is based on an old version of nethack and I can't convince it to open windowed (even when using the --windowed option).

So, what are some easy to install nethack ports with graphical interface and big tiles, preferably commanded via keyboard? What options could help me achieve that with xnethack?

Comment: Have you tried some of the other options that appear if you search 'nethack' in a package manager (I'm tried Muon as I'm currently running lubuntu; but `apt search nethack` would probably get a similar list if you like commands, or use another package manager)

Comment: yes, glhack came from such a search